# SQL COUNT против SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS + FOUND_ROWS()

Tags: mysqli, sql

Всем привет!

Пару лет назад нашел такую замечательную штуку SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS и вот вспомнил про неё(пригодилась), но в отличии от тогдашнего наткнулся в stackoverflow на многочисленные рекомендации использовать заместо неё COUNT() в связи с тем, что первый способ якобы медленнее на большие таблицы. Я удивился конечно, но решил проверить. Вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    tblA.*, 
    tblB.id AS 'b_id', 
    tblB.city AS 'b_city',
    tblC.id AS 'c_id', 
    tblC.type AS 'c_type', 
    tblD.id AS 'd_id', 
    tblD.extype AS 'd_extype', 
    tblY.id AS 'y_id', 
    tblY.ydt AS 'y_ydt' 
FROM 
    tblA, 
    tblB, 
    tblC, 
    tblD, 
    tblY 
WHERE 
    tblA.b = tblC.id AND 
    tblA.c = tblB.id AND 
    tblA.d = tblD.id AND 
    tblA.y = tblY.id
ORDER BY 
    id
LIMIT 
    1,50
```

InnoDB, проиндексирована. Записей в каждой табличке немного(+- 100)

Проверка из 10 запросов показала:

```
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS + FOUND_ROWS() = 0.092

COUNT() = 0.26
```

брал результат выполнения всей страницы на сервере функцией microtime(1)

**Вопросы:**

Как по вашему, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS + FOUND_ROWS() лучше? Если не всегда, то в каких случаях нет? Ну и любые советы по оптимизации и .т.п, приветствуются.